# Does Get-NetIPConfiguration return interfaces in binding order?

Tags: powershell

I noticed that

```
(Get-NetIPConfiguration).InterfaceIndex
```

always seems to return the index's in interface binding order for me. is this the way its suppose to function, always returning in interface binding order or it is just a fluke that it always returns in interface binding order for me in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
(Get-NetIPConfiguration).InterfaceIndex | Sort [int]
```

Comment: yes, I could if I wanted them arranged in order of interface 'number' value but that's not what i'm after/asking because that 'sort' may not always be the binding order. For example, interface index 3 could be binding to interface index 6 but there is also an interface with an index of 5. If I sort them like that they will no longer be in binding order.

Comment: My Bad.. Just looking through the properties for ````Get-NetIPConfiguration | get-member ```` to see what property would store that information. Nothing sticking out at the moment.

Comment: also, the linkage registry key, Windows 10, on my system has the bindings that match what Get-NetIPConfiguration gives me indexes in the same order as the guid's appear at the key except the very first one which is bound to all interfaces in Windows 10 which is the 'Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter' which does not get an Ip address so it will not show up with Get-NetIPConfiguration. Its beginning to look like Get-NetIPConfiguration does give the binding order, I know (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration).InterfaceIndex returns all in binding order Ip enabled or not.

Comment: As an aside: I assume you meant `{ [int] $_ }` rather than `[int]`. Passing just a _type_ to `Sort-Object` doesn't work (unless the input objects happen to be `[int]` instances anyway, as in this case, where the `[int]` is effectively ignored).

Answer (score 0):

ok, got this figured out. Starting with windows 10 the preferred IP Address enabled (either IPv4 or IPv6) interface is the one with the lowest sum of the IPv4 (or IPv4) route metric and the interface metric (route metric + if metric). This may not be the one with the default route 0.0.0.0/0 depending on if you have multiple interfaces set up or not with multiple default routes. That interface will bind to the one with the next lowest lowest sum on the same route ...and so forth and so on. This also, it turns out, may not be the order of the interface GUID's in the registry value at 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\Currentcontrolset\Services\TCPIP\Linkage\bind\

But...how they appear in a list, including other methods, is determined just by the interface metric. So in Windows 10 there is (i'm gonna call it) 'route binding order' and the list order. Although this may seem to match up sometimes because most people don't have multiple interfaces in their systems it becomes important if you are going to start playing around with setting interface and route metric to ensure the interface you want to be used is the one being used for a particular route. So you want the actual binding order and not the list order.

so, in windows 10, to get correct route binding order (vs list order) you have to examine the route table and do the 'math' for sum of route metric + interface metric to get actual binding order, and use that same 'sum' methodolgy to set up interfaces if you are going to do it yourself.

Below is an example of this method usage that i threw together quickly. I have one Windows 10 machine with two hardware interfaces, one for hard line connection and the other wifi. I also have OpenVPN with a TAP adapter installed on this system, so i need to know which hardware interface that OpenVPN was binding to through the TAP adapter. The TAP adapter is a virtual (software) interface. When the TAP is installed/connected it uses a interface metric less than 10 because windows minimum automatic interface metric is always no lower than 10 (although you can manually set it lower) , and the tap uses a route metric of 0. So the tap is going to be the lowest 'sum' Ip enabled interface in the system. So all this info and using the below code I got the hardware interface the Open/VPN/Tap is binding to (code thrown together quickly, will refine later when I have the time)..

```
$route = (Get-NetRoute); $rtmetric = $route.RouteMetric; $ifmetric = $route.InterfaceMetric; $index = $route.ifIndex;
$sumarray = @(); $indexarray = @(); For ($i=0; $i -lt $rtmetric.Length; $i++)

  {
    $sum = $rtmetric[$i] + $ifmetric[$i]
    $sumarray += $sum 
    $indexarray += $index[$i]
  }

$sumsort = $sumarray | sort -unique; [int]$sumlowest = ($sumsort | measure -Minimum).Minimum;
$pos = [Array]::indexof($sumsort,$sumlowest) + 1; $sumget = $sumsort[$pos]; $posA = [Array]::indexof($sumarray,$sumget); $ifindexbind = $indexarray[$posA];
(Get-NetAdapter | ? ifIndex -eq $ifindexbind)
```

so, that's the long way around it to get the route binding order vs the list order. If you do this:

```
(Get-NetAdapter).InstanceID
```

you will get the binding in list order as they are in the registry key starting from the bottom and working your way up. But.... if you do this

```
(Get-NetIPConfiguration).NetAdapter.InstanceID
```

you will notice that as interfaces are disabled or enable the order given will also change, and that's because '(Get-NetIPConfiguration).NetAdapter.InstanceID' is giving the route binding order and not the registry list order. Disabling an interface removes it from the route table but just disabling an interface does not remove its binding to another interface but the priority changes so the previously bound interface now becomes the preferred interface in the route so moves to the top. When that disabled interface with the binding to the enabled interface, is enabled again it takes it place in the route binding on top. The one on top will be the preferred adapter (the one with the lowest 'sum' value), the one under that will be the 'next prefered' (the one with the next lowest 'sum' value) and if on the same route is the interface bound to one above it, thus binding order. So using (Get-NetIPConfiguration).NetAdapter.InstanceID the needed route binding order for enabled and connected interfaces can be had without resorting to reading the registry.